# How to run mutiple ElastAlert rules

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastalert

I am learning to use ElastAlert. I would like to run multi cardinality rule by ElasAlert or using a better solution.

For example,

```
filter:
- query:
    query_string:
      query: "message: *A*"

filter:
- query:
    query_string:
      query: "message: *B*"

filter:
- query:
    query_string:
      query: "message: *C*"
```

I have few condition need to monitor, any of them lower than 1 message per minute I will need to received an alter. Is that possible to be run in one rule or I can run it in a multiple process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your rule_x.yaml file like

filter:
    - query:
        query_string: 
            query: "message: A OR message: B OR message: C"

and follow the other configuration options in the documentation
https://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

```
filter:
- query:
    query_string: 
        query: '"message: A OR message: B OR message: C"'
```

As note:
withing single quote pass your elasticsearch query as it is within '' (that is single quote)